# Переполнение метода initialize в ruby

Tags: ruby, полиморфизм

Хочу реализовать несколько способов создания объекта, переполняя метод initialize.

class Coord

```
attr_accessor :x, :y

# Create the object
def initialize (x, y)
    @x = x
    @y = y
end
```

end

class Base

```
attr_accessor :coordinates


# Create the object by Coord
def initialize (coord = Coord.new(0, 0))
    @coordinates = coord if Coord === coord
end


# Create the object by x, y
def initialize (x, y)
    @coordinates = Coord.new(x, y)
end
```

end

c = Coord.new(1, 2)
base = Base.new(c)

при запуске:
`initialize': wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2) (ArgumentError)

подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Comment: *переполняя*? [Перегружая](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%80_%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9), может?

Comment: да, перегрузка) все верно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### В Ruby нет перегрузки методов.

Определив `initialize` во второй раз, пусть и другой арности (числа аргументов), вы **заменили** его, а не добавили новую форму.

Принимайте такой набор аргументов, что способен представить все нужные вам, и разбирайтесь уже внутри метода, что вы получили.

Скажем, принимать 1 или 2 аргумента можно, например, если принимать "сколько угодно":

```
def initialize(*args)
```

Так в `args` будет массив всех переданных аргументов. Вы не получите `wrong number of arguments`, сколько бы аргументов ни передали — определить, что аргументы некорректны и бабахнуть своим `ArgumentError`'ом нужно будет уже внутри.

---

Ruby достаточно гибок, чтобы реализовать в нём перегрузку библиотечными средствами, есть [реализация перегрузки в геме `contracts`](https://egonschiele.github.io/contracts.ruby/#method-overloading), но это уже не средства языка.

---

Но для простоты поддержки лучше просто сделать и задокументировать два разных метода у класса.